# Get distance of each country in Google Maps (Angular)

Tags: angular, agm

I use AgmCoreModule and AgmDirectionModule in my Angular project. I want to draw a route between points A, B, C which goes through different countries. I want to know how many kilometers of route are in each country separately. Is it possible? Or should you use some different library?

Comment: I've done something similar using leaflet, here's a good guide: https://oramind.com/country-border-highlighting-with-leaflet-js/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the distance in a straight line (like a plane) but with the curvature of the earth/elevation considered, I think [@turf/distance](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-distance) is a good option.

If you want to calculate through a path on a map (with streets and such, literally going from A to B), you'll have to use the google maps directions API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

AGM has a certain implementation which is third party and a bit fishy:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-direction

I have used it successfully in the past.

Otherwise you can use google's official sdk:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js